# How to change timeout using RabbitMQ pika.basic_consume in Python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

With the RabbitMQ Python client running `subscriber.py`:

```
    import pika, time 

    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user', 'pass')
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost', port=6672, credentials=credentials)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.queue_declare(queue='my_queue')

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        time.sleep(600)
        print ('process completed')

    channel.basic_consume(queue='my_queue', on_message_callback=callback)
    channel.start_consuming()
```

the connection breaks after the `callback` function is completed.
It appears it always happens on 60th second. It seems the `channel.basic_consume()` method doesn't want to wait for the main thread to complete the callback function. Is there a way to make sure the connection doesn't drop after 60th second?

Comment: What exception is raised when the connection breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `time.sleep` call is blocking Pika's I/O loop which prevents heartbeats from being processed. **Don't block the I/O loop!!!**

Instead, you should do your long-running work in a separate thread and acknowledge the message correctly from that thread. Fortunately, I have [an example](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py) right here: [link](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py)

Comment: I tried the code as mentioned in the link. But I am still the same error. I am setting the prefetch count to 1, so that the thread list doesn't overflow causing OutOfMemory error. My code: https://gist.github.com/sathishbabu96/73d4f677cdfb4787f7d7e79fc27e6034

Comment: That code sample isn't runnable as `ConnectionHandler` isn't included, so I don't want to guess at the issue. I know the example works, so start from there, or provide code that _I can run_ that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Sorry, that the code doesn't work. I will explain my scenario. I am using RabbitMQ to train my ML models. As explained in your example code for long-running jobs, I am just replacing the `time.sleep()` method with my training process which takes a fair amount of time. But, I am still facing the same Connection Reset error.

Comment: What is logged by RabbitMQ at the same time as the "connection reset"?

Comment: @LukeBakken: sorry, but the example doesn't seem to be good if there are a lot of messages being processed. You store in the list each of the threads and if you have millions of messages processed, this doesn't scale well IMO.

Comment: Correct, it's an _example_. Pika's _examples_ are not intended for production use.

Comment: @LukeBakken what is the motivation for https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py#L36 i.e `conn.add_callback_threadsafe(cb)`? If `auto_ack=True` would it serve any purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I think the "heartbeat" parameter solves this problem. Just set the time in seconds:

```
import pika, time 

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user', 'pass')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost', port=6672, credentials=credentials, heartbeat=36000)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.queue_declare(queue='my_queue')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    time.sleep(600)
    print ('process completed')

channel.basic_consume(queue='my_queue', on_message_callback=callback)
channel.start_consuming()
```